# Does $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\dots$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does
>   $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\dots$$
>   converge?

**What I have tried:**

The series diverges since $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}-\dots=(1-\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4})+\dots=\sum(\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{k+1})$$ and it can be shown that $$\sum \frac{1}{k+1}$$ diverges.

However, I am not sure at all if this is correct or not. Am I allowed to re-group the terms like that? I think there would be a more elegant way to do this ...

Comment: Reciprocals (negative terms) diverge, reciprocal squares (positive terms) converge, so cannot restrain the divergence.

Comment: Yes, this series diverges to $-\infty$.  You have some ideas for a proof.  Instead of the imprecise "allowed to re-group them", maybe use partial sums and see what you can do with that.

Comment: Regrouping is allowed in infinite sums, in case of convergence. This is an "infinite associative law". However, you cannot simply change the order as conditional convergence demonstrates. This can be proved by the Cauchy condition, but I don't know if it'd be easier to show that than tackle just this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove directly that the series diverges by doing, for $k\geq3$,
$$
\frac1 {k^2}-\frac1 {k+1}=\frac {k+1-k^2}{(k+1)k^2}<\frac {-k^2}{2 (k+1)k^2}=-\frac12\,\frac1 {k+1}
$$
and the series diverges by comparison.

Comment: can you please explain the two last steps?

Comment: The last step is $k^2/k^2=1$; and there was a 2 missing in the last term. What else is not clear?

Comment: why $$
\frac {k+1-k^2}{(k+1)k^2}<\frac {-k^2}{2 (k+1)k^2}??$$

Comment: Because $k+1<k^2/2$ when $k\geq3$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't converge; your method is valid.  There is this thing called the Reimann Rearrangement theorem.  Consider$$\sum _1 ^\infty {(-1)^{x+1}\over x}$$  This gives ${1\over 1}-{1\over 2} +{1\over 3} -{1\over4}...$  It can be shown that this converges to $\ln2$.  However, notice that if you add up the positive terms, it goes to infinity, and the negative terms add up to negative infinity.  So you can actually rearrange the terms to get any number.  For example, let's say you wanted to get them to add to $\pi$.  You add only positive terms until they get to a value above $\pi$.  Then you subtract the first negative term, and get a value beneath $\pi$.  You add again till it goes above $\pi$, and then you subtract the next negative term, getting a value beneath $\pi$.  This process is repeated, and the value tends toward $\pi$.  This works for any series which is conditionally convergent.  The series you gave as an example is not.  You are allowed to rearrange them like that.  The method you used was correct.  Keep in mind the above, however, as that method may not always work.